# Habitable moon and hycean world

Tags: planets, moons, habitability

A hycean world is a cross between a rocky planet and a gas giant. Think an ocean world with an atmosphere full of hydrogen.

Assuming it is in the habitable zone of its star, could a habitable moon, basically like Pandora, orbit this planet? I think it's interesting to have two habitable worlds right next to each other.

Comment: Note that Pandora is a very uninhabitable moon of Saturn - if you are referring to a fictitious one then a link would be appropriate.  There have been many, many questions on this site about habitable moons around various types of planets - what is special about a hycean world that makes you think it would prevent a moon being habitable?

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 I suspect he means Pandora from the movie *Avatar.* Joe, we have no evidence that an hycean world can exist, does exist, or can be habitable. I believe we do have evidence for binary planets, so when you say "moon," you might be limiting yourself. It's plausible that two habitable binary planets can exist, and assuming a hycean world can be habitable, the answer to your question is "yes." From this perspective the question is likely to be closed as a duplciate of any number of "can two habitable binary planets exist?" questions that have been asked before.

Comment: In other words, I'm giving you a chance to consider deleting the question before what I believe will be an inevitable closure. Keep in mind it's worth searching this site using general terms (@KerrAvon2055 is correct, there's nothing special about hycean planets to make this question unique) before posting questions.

Comment: Too late.......

Comment: [Pandora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandora), meaning "All-Gifted" in Greek, was the first woman, created by Hephaestus at the order of Zeus, and sent among the mortals [carrying a jar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandora's_box) in which the angered god had placed neverending curses and sorrows. It is quite common, especially in the *Thousand and One Nights*, to speak about a woman as beautiful as the moon; but I have no idea what is to be understood by a moon similar to a woman. VTC as unclear what the question is about.

Comment: It is _fascinating_ (by which I mean depressing) how many people on this site completely lose their theory of mind and become unable to read anything that isn't some kind of legalese.

Comment: @StarfishPrime What is that referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the size of the hycean world and moon. Seeing that hycean worlds are only hypothetical we can only guess how big they can be, but they will be bigger than Earth. The moon will also have to be big, essentially making the system a binary-planet system and not a planet and moon. A habitable moon needs a gravitational field, an approximent 24 hour rotation period, water vapor in the atmosphere, and up to 35% of its mass located in the core(This is called Core Mass Fraction). The gravitational field keeps the atmosphere on the moon. The rotation period creates a magnetic field that protects the atmosphere from solar radiation. The water vapor is because it is one of the key ingredients of chemical formulas and the basis of life. The CMF is meant to be near or above 35% of the planet's mass so that it creates an active core. From the [Worldsmith](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AML0mIQcWDrrEHj-InXoYsV_QlhlFVuUalE3o-TwQco/copy) by [Artifexian](https://www.youtube.com/c/Artifexian).

> For habitable Earth-like planets, it is recommended to chose a CMF value close to Earth's CMF (35%). This will ensure that your planets is capable of generating a sufficiently protective magnetic field, thus making your planet habitable.

Comment: The rotation period alone isn't enough to provide a magnetic field. Look at the length of the Martian day. It is also likely to be somewhat less in a binary planet system than in a planet+small moon setup.

Comment: @StarfishPrime That is true. An active core is also needed to churn up the magnetic metals. I have seen this measured as Core Mass Fraction or CMF. Earth has a CMF of around 35%. This means 35% of Earth's mass is located in the core.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes and no**

Yes as in, a habitable moon can exist around a hycean world. No as in, the hycean world won't remain in this unstable equilibrium for long enough to develop life, it will either lose hydrogen from its atmosphere and stop being hycean (but having helium could alter something, otherwise it'll be a terran world), or gain more hydrogen and turn into a gas giant.